# Using independence_test in R with unequal sample sizes

Tags: r, self-study, permutation-test

This is a homework problem that I have where I'm testing the means of sampled high temperatures in two cities:  Des Moines and Chicago.  The first part of the question required me to run an unpaired t-test which I was able to do.

The second part asked me to use a permutation test on the same data.  Unfortunately, there are unequal sample sizes (Des Moines:  9, Chicago:  8) and I get an error when I use the independence_test in the coin package in R.

A similar question on this site mentioned that it should be easy to code this comparison using this package but went on to write longer code that did the calculations itself.  I can adapt that code, but I was curious if there's a shorter way to code it in the independence_test within the coin package.  Here's what I have and the error I get:

```
> desmoines<-c(83,91,94,89,89,96,91,92,90)
> chicago<-c(78,82,81,77,79,81,80,81)
> library(coin)
> independence_test(desmoines~chicago)
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 8, 9
```

Answer (score 0):

**Comment:** Perhaps you can explain why you're doing an independence test, especially with two data vectors of different length.

> Are some of the data from one city from the same years as from the other city? What 'linkage' between cities makes you ask about independence? The correlation between Chi and the first 8 elements in Des is about 0.7:  the statement `cor(c,d[1:8])` returns 0.6939698, but that's largely due to the one point $(83,78).$

Without knowing more of the story, my first impulse was to do a Welch
2-sample t test. I indulged this impulse--perhaps without due deliberation--and the test rejects the null hypothesis of equal population means with a tiny P-value (5.298e-06).

Also, box plots on the same scale
pretty clearly show that the two cities differ greatly in whatever
measure you are using here. The data for the two cities are 
completely separated by the value 82.5 (red line).

[image]

If this is not helpful, then please tell us what you're really trying
to find out and maybe someone will answer.

Comment: Sorry.  I'm trying to do a permutation test because my homework problem asks me to do it both ways and I was able to code for a Welch's two sample t-test.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and I've edited the question to make it clear that it's a HW problem.  When I said "both ways," I was referring to how the question asks me to run an unpaired t-test and a permutation test.  I was able to code the Welch's test but ran into this error for the permutation test.  Thanks for your times so far and any more help is appreciated

Comment: _Repairing damaged comment formerly posted above, now deleted._: A permutation test to determine whether the means of the two groups will surely reject: Out of ${17\choose 8}=24,310$ ways to allocate 8 values to Chicago, only one of them gives the 8 lowest values to that city. So that takes care of permutation test. You already have Welch test. So you should be able to finish this.